# String theory assumes that strings are complex geometric objects

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, complex-numbers

In string theory, a string is a one-dimensional space that can be closed on itself as a circle (closed string) or open as a linear interval (open string), but does a string have one real dimension or does it mean one complex dimension?

Comment: It is correct to think of a fundamental string as a space? Never seen it before and it does not seem so. A string is a one-dimensional extended object. In critical superstring theory you have ten real spacetime dimensions. The one dimensional string propagates. The two-dimensional string worldsheet -which is a manifold- describes the string embedding.

Comment: http://www.emanuelmalek.com/Teaching/Complex/Chapter3.pdf page 8. Euclidean string worldsheet is a complex manifold

Comment: @MitchellPorter I do not see how the link you sent disagrees with what I wrote to be honest. I would be grateful if you could explain. It is a very nice presentation, by the way

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 My comment was for exxxit88, who asked if a string has one complex dimension. Now that I look at the question again, I see it seems to be asking about an "instantaneous" string, rather than the history of the string, so perhaps should add, the instantaneous string indeed only has one real dimension. For something with two real spacelike dimensions, you'd need a 2-brane.

Comment: @MitchellPorter thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

A string is a 1 (real) dimensional object - it is simply an extension of a point into one higher dimension.

A string *theory* describes how a string behaves in an ambient spacetime of some higher dimension through the embedding of the string into this ambient spacetime. This embedding results in a two real dimensional surface (called the worldsheet) with complex structure which is roughly thought of as the string+its history (it is exactly analogous to a worldline). Because of the complex structure it makes sense to say the string worldsheet is 1 complex dimensional.